# How to launch a url in the new window of firefox browser using C#

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, browser

I want to launch my url in the new window of firefox browser. As of now, every time I launch the url, a new tab gets added to the existing window which I don't want.

Here is my piece of code:

```
 Uri url = new Uri("https://www/google.com");
 Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
 {
    FileName = "firefox.exe",
    Arguments = url.ToString() + "--new window",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order* and you're using too many dashes before 'new-window'; The correct order is:

```
Arguments = "-new-window " + url.ToString(),
```